# SQLite: Cannot delete row in database

Tags: sqlite

I have the code as following to insert data into TestDB database, I can do insert and delete all rows successful but Delete one row didn't work.

Please show me what's wrong with the code. I think the problem comes from the function deleteRow not recognize the column1 value.

Thanks

```
<script>

    var db = window.openDatabase("Test", "1.0", "Test DB", 1000000);
    var column1= document.getElementById("column1");
    var column2= document.getElementById("column2");
    var column3= document.getElementById("column3");
    var results = document.getElementById("results");
    var id = document.getElementById('id');     
    var Delete = document.getElementById('Delete');     


    function InsertDB(){
       if ((column1.value!='') && (column2.value!='') && (column3.value!='')) {
      db.transaction(function(tx) {
          tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TestDB (id INTEGER, column1 TEXT, column2 TEXT, column3 TEXT)');
          tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO TestDB (column1, column2, column3) VALUES (?, ?, ?)', [column1.value, column2.value, column3.value], ShowandReset);
    }); 
    }
         else alert("Column cannot be empty");
    }



    function ShowDB() { 
    results.innerHTML = ''; 
    db.transaction(function(tx) {

      tx.executeSql("SELECT * FROM TestDB", [], function(tx, result) {
        dataset = result.rows;
        for (var i = 0, item = null; i < dataset.length; i++) {
         item = dataset.item(i);
         results.innerHTML += item['column1'] + ' , ' + item['column2'] + ' , ' + item['column3'] + '   ' + '<a href="#" onclick="deleteRow('+item['column1']+')"> Delete this row</a>' + '</br>';
        }               

        });
            });
                        }


function deleteRow(a) {

   db.transaction(function(tx) {
        tx.executeSql("DELETE FROM TestDB WHERE column1=a");
        });
        ShowDB();
        }

function DeleteDB() {
   db.transaction(function(tx) {
        tx.executeSql("DELETE FROM TestDB");
        });
        ShowDB();
        } 

function resetForm(){
    column1.value = '';
    column2.value = '';
    column3.value = '';
    id.value = ''; 
    }
function ShowandReset(){ 
    resetForm();
    ShowDB();
    }
function LoadRow(i) {

    var item = dataset.item(i);     
    column1.value = item['column1'];
    column2.value = item['column2'];
    column3.value = item['column3'];
    id.value = item['id']; 
    }


</script>
```

Comment: Not sure where and how this will be run, but keep in mind that anyone with access to your site, will be able to run arbitrary queries on your database.

Comment: When you unsure in something, use command interpreter to learn how to write requests correctly.

Comment: Also, i'm agreed with @GrimaceofDespair, you sould use defence mechanisms from an attack on your site. Sql injection is most common way to ruin your job.

Comment: This is a test database for practice purpose and I think nothing inside the database is useful.

Answer (score 1):

Ok new solution now that the problem has been clarified.

```
function deleteRow(a)
{
//a is a paramete
//this is a query string, so you need to append a otherwise it is interpreted litterally
 var queryString = "DELETE FROM TestDB WHERE column1='"+a+"'";
//Execute queryString as before
}
```

Comment: You cannot delete a row from a database, a database contains a list of tables, tables contain rows.  If you want to remove a table from a Database you use DROP, you want to remove a particular row from a table. Are you less confused now?

I suppose test DB should be called testTable or testTab.

Anyway I've found your syntax error:
DELETE FROM TestDB WHERE column1='a'

String litterals must be escaped.

Comment: Thanks, What i wanna do is remove one row that i already added by insertDB() function.
I tried "DELETE FROM TestDB WHERE column1='a'", "DELETE FROM TestDB WHERE column1=a" and "DELETE FROM TestDB WHERE column1=?,[a]" but none of them is woking.
I tried using "DELETE FROM TestDB WHERE column1=1" and the row have column value=1 is deleted.
The problem must be the function deleteRow(a) doesn't recognize a is a value.

Comment: Do you mean ?
`function deleteRow(a) {
      var queryString = "DELETE FROM TestDB WHERE column1='"+a+"'";
       db.transaction(function(tx) {
         tx.executeSql(queryString);
        });`
I do as above but it not working

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
db.transaction(function (tx) {
        tx.executeSql('DELETE FROM TestTable', []);
    });
```

with WHERE clause:

```
db.transaction(function (tx) {
        tx.executeSql('DELETE FROM TestTable WHERE COLUMN = ?', [yourValue]);
    });
```